# Zend data cache TTL not working

Tags: php, caching, zend-server

I'm using zend_shm_cache functions as a fast storage of variables. My problem is that the cache doesn't seem to get cleared after TTL is over. Example:

```
zend_shm_cache_store( $key = 'test3', 'value', 2 );
foreach( range(1,5) as $timer ){
    sleep( 1 );
    echo $timer.' - ' .zend_shm_cache_fetch( $key ).'<br/>';
}
```

Returns:

```
1 - value
2 - 
3 - value
4 - value
5 - value
```

I would expect the cache to be empty after second second. Can you explain what's happening or propose a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer in the documentation of APCU:

> After the ttl has passed, the stored variable will be expunged from
>   the cache (on the next request).

As my code runs in only one request the cache is never deleted even when its time has expired.